# wgrep cannot modify read-only files?

Tags: replace

I am using `wgrep` but somehow for those read-only files (under version control), it always reports not to apply changes. Even the var of `wgrep-change-readonly-file` is set to `t`. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The [Github README](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep) says that the variable actually means read-only *buffers*, not read-only *files*:

> To apply all changes wheather or not **buffer** is read-only.
>
> ```
> (setq wgrep-change-readonly-file t)
> ```

You cannot modify read-only files by definition. You must adjust the files' attributes in order to do so. This varies depending on your operating system and file system.

Comment: I tried to open them in advanced, but it still does not work and can not change the read-only property of these buffers. Are these steps correct?

Comment: @macs I just tried it out, and it works fine.